# How to access values of an array within an array inside JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I access each value of `features` array within every `condo` and `house` element?
I tried it like so:

```
attr.features.name,
```

... but `undefined` pops up in the web console.

**JSON**:

```
({condos:[{Address:'123 Fake St.', Lat:'56.645654', Lng:'23.534546', features:[{id:'1', name:'Swimming Pool'},{id:'2', name:'BBQ'},{..etc..}]},{... another condo ...},{...}],houses:[{Address:'1 Main Ave.', Lat:'34.765766', Lng:'27.8786674', features:[{...},{...}]},{... another house ...}, {...}]})
```

**Code**:

```
    $.each(markers, function(type, elements) {
        $.each(elements, function(index, attr){
            // if it's a house - make house marker. if it's a condo - make condo marker.
            if (type == 'houses') {
                $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'features': attr.features.name, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(attr.lat), parseFloat(attr.lng)), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'house.png' });
            }
            else if (type == 'condos') {
                $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'features': attr.features.name, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(attr.lat), parseFloat(attr.lng)), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'condo.png' });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object with Two Arrays. You should access each array separately

```
$(markers.condos).each(function(index, elem) {
    $('#map').gmap('addMarker', {
        'features': elem.features,
        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(elem.lat), parseFloat(elem.lng)),
        'bounds': true,
        'icon': 'condo.png'
    });
});​
```

and same for `markers.houses`

Comment: But wouldn't the `elem.features` access both `id` and `name` of `features` array? I want to only access the `name`.

Comment: You have an array of features in your JSON. Which name would you like to access?